# How to reset proxy to default setting?

Tags: proxy, https

I'm cloning from github and got an error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com|  ~
>       /scrooloose/nerdcommenter.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port                                     8087: Connection refused

I remember that I set an proxy before which leads to the error. Is there any method to set proxy settings to default?

Comment: Where/how did you change the proxy settings? Have you tried going to `System Settings` --> `Network` --> `Network Proxy` and setting `Method` to `None`?